# Form html not secure when I host the page online

Tags: html, forms

I made an html form input (Name, Mail, Comment). When I show the page with localhost (with visual studio code) I have not problem. But when I host website with github and I put the cursor inside an input area, I see the message: "this form is not secure. Autofill has been turned off".

This is the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFarc.png
And this is the code:

```
<form action="mailto:tomaigabriele@gmail.com" method="post" name = "user" enctype="text/plain">
    <section class="contact_form">  
        <div id="name_mail">Name</div>
        <div id="content">Surname</div>
    </section>   
    <div id="button_contact">
        <button class='btn-xl' type='submit'>Send</button>
        <button class='btn-xl' type='reset'>reset</button>
    </div> 
    
</form>
```

I'm not using currently php.

Thank you

Comment: is it hosted on https? i do not know if browsers treat `mailto` as insecure or not. you should consider submitting the form to a server backend.

Comment: To @DanielA.White's point, if you aren't on SSL the browser might just be cautioning the user. I would start by getting rid of the `name = "user"` attribute since it might be thinking the form is a login form.

Comment: mailto is not possible with secured... better you use post form and then send mail with mail or phpmailer etc...

Comment: **mailto** attribute has been known vulnerable not for what it does on browsers, but for what it might does  by email clients (e.g. Thunderbird), such as sending sensitive files like ssh keys as an attachment. See [this](https://www.zdnet.com/article/some-email-clients-are-vulnerable-to-attacks-via-mailto-links/)